# How can I catch following web element using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

[image]I want to catch the login button in the NavBar and I am new to selenium still. How can I catch the login button? I have tried containText, class etc. but no result yet. I tried this but did not work for me

//button[text()='login']

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Login text is not directly under button tag.
Use //button//*[text()='LOGIN']